# How to pass to Razor view an anonymous type that contains collections?

Tags: linq, razor, anonymous-types

I am attempting to pass a collection of anonymous types which has in itself a collection of types to the Razor view engine.

I am using the following extension to pass dynamic objects to the view.

```
 public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object anonymousObject)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(anonymousObject);
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
            expando.Add(item);
        return (ExpandoObject)expando;
    }
```

It works with simple anonymous objects such as:

```
mylinqstatement.Select(x => new { foo = x.f, bar = x.b }.ToExpando());
```

However, I have been unsuccessful in passing a more complex type such as:

```
mylinqstatement.GroupBy(y => y.foo).Select(x => 
     new { foo = x.key, bar = x.Select(y => y.b) }.ToExpando());
```

I have made several attempts to rewrite the ladder statement (I showed the simplest), but the property I want (the value of y.b) is never accessible within the view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put your answer in an Answer rather than as an edit to your question.

Comment: It won't let me for several more hours. I'll do so when it unlocks the ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question.

```
mylinqstatement.GroupBy(y => y.foo).Select(x => new { foo = x.key, 
 bar = x.Select(y => new { someProperty = y.b) }.ToExpando())}.ToExpando());
```

In the view...

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
 @item.foo

 foreach (var barItem in item.bar)  //<--- notice it's not simply 'in item'. 
{
 @barItem .someProperty 
}

}
```

Hopefully this can help someone to avoid unnecessary headache.